# How to get a Kerberos token in Python? I have working C# and PS syntax but would like to convert it

Tags: python, c#, dll, kerberos

I'm trying to use Python to get a Kerberos security token. I have some C# sharp syntax that does want I need but I have no clue where to begin to converting that to Python.  Here is the C# code:

```
{
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            var domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().ToString();
            using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                KerberosSecurityTokenProvider tokenProvider = new KerberosSecurityTokenProvider(serviceName, System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
                KerberosRequestorSecurityToken securityToken = tokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)) as KerberosRequestorSecurityToken;
                string serviceToken = Convert.ToBase64String(securityToken.GetRequest());
}
```

I've tried to use the 'microsoft.identitymodel.dll' and using the ctype and clr library, but, I am pretty new to Python so I'm not sure if that's even the correct avenue.  I also have some Powershell code that does what I need as such:

`[System.IdentityModel.Selectors.KerberosSecurityTokenProvider]$tokenProvider = [System.IdentityModel.Selectors.KerberosSecurityTokenProvider]::new($ServicePrincipalName, [System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel]::Identification, $PSBoundParameters.Credential)`

I know what the $ServicePrincipalName should be and I know I could use the subprocess library and just call the command using Powershell.exe, but I wanted to keep everything in Python.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The primary interface to Windows authentication is **[SSPI](https://github.com/jborean93/pyspnego)** (likewise GSSAPI on Linux). The C#/PS (CLR) libraries are just fancy wrappers around SSPI, so it would be a waste of time trying to use them from Python – it's easier to directly use one of the Python SSPI modules.

Summary:

- If you need this for ordinary HTTP requests:
  use "requests-kerberos" as a plugin for 'requests'.
- If you need this for a custom HTTP client or some other SPNEGO-based protocol:
  use "python-pyspnego" as the cross-platform solution.
- If you need raw (non-SPNEGO) Kerberos:
  use either "sspilib" or pywin32 "sspi" on Windows, and "python-gssapi" on Linux.

##### python-pyspnego

Since most Windows protocols use SPNEGO rather than raw Kerberos, **[python-pyspnego](https://github.com/jborean93/pyspnego)** would be the best choice for cross-platform operation – it provides a unified interface to SPNEGO over both Windows SSPI and over Unix GSSAPI. (It can also do NTLM on Unix.)

The basic model of SSPI/GSSAPI is to call step() in a loop until the mechanism reports it's done:

```python
import spnego

ctx = spnego.client(hostname="foo.example.com",
                    service="HTTP",
                    protocol="negotiate")

while not ctx.complete:
    # [receive in_token from server...]
    out_token = ctx.step(in_token)
    # [send out_token to server, receive another in_token back...]
```

But for HTTP Negotiate authentication there is just one step (and the input token is usually empty; Kerberos is a "client starts first" mechanism), so you can skip the loop and just call `step()` once:

```python
import spnego

ctx = spnego.client(hostname="foo.example.com",
                    service="HTTP",
                    protocol="negotiate")

in_token = None
out_token = ctx.step(in_token)
```

##### sspilib and sspi/pywin32

The `spnego` module is a high-level wrapper around platform-specific modules. If you're working exclusively on Windows, you can also directly use either the new **[sspilib](https://github.com/jborean93/sspilib)** module:

```python
import sspilib

creds = sspilib.UserCredential(usage="initiate",
                               protocol="Negotiate",
                               protocol_list=["!ntlm"])

ctx = sspilib.ClientSecurityContext(target_name="HTTP/foo.example.com",
                                    credential=creds)

out_token = ctx.step(in_token)
```

…or the older **sspi** module which is part of [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

```python
import sspi

ctx = sspi.ClientAuth("Negotiate",
                      targetspn="HTTP/foo.example.com")

in_token = None
err, bufs = ctx.authorize(in_token)
assert err == 0
out_token = bufs[0].Buffer
```

##### gssapi

The Linux/Unix equivalent of the `sspi` module would be **[python-gssapi](https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi)**, which uses very similar concepts. By default it deals with raw Kerberos tokens, but this example asks it to speak SPNEGO:

```python
import gssapi

SPNEGO = gssapi.Mechanism.from_sasl_name("SPNEGO")

target = gssapi.Name("HTTP@foo.example.com",
                     gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)

ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(name=target,
                             mech=SPNEGO,
                             usage="initiate")

in_token = None
out_token = ctx.step(in_token)
```

(Note: **do not** install the `gssapi` module on Windows – if you do, then the `spnego` module will stop using SSPI and will start complaining about missing MIT GSSAPI libraries.)

##### Others

Two other modules exist: [pykerberos](https://pypi.org/project/pykerberos/) for GSSAPI (Unix) and [winkerberos](https://pypi.org/project/winkerberos/) for SSPI (Windows). They work similarly, but the API they provide is a bit ugly and non-Pythonic (pykerberos was originally a wrapper for Objective-C interfaces in MacOS).

##### HTTP

And of course if you're trying to use this for HTTP, there already are several modules for that – e.g. [requests-kerberos](https://pypi.org/project/requests-kerberos/) adds SSPI (and GSSAPI) support through pyspnego:

```python
import requests
import requests_kerberos

resp = requests.get("https://foo.example.com",
                    auth=requests_kerberos.HTTPKerberosAuth())
```

Similarly, [requests-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/requests-gssapi/) and [httpx-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/httpx-gssapi/) do the same via `gssapi` on Unix.

##### Other languages

- Golang: alexbrainman/sspi (probably?), openshift/gssapi, *(not gokrb5)*
- Java: Waffle, probably?
- Rust: sspi-rs (native on Windows but uses a custom Kerberos implementation on Linux)

Comment: Thank you SO much for this information.  I will try the info here! I'm thinking the SSPI should have what I need.