# SPNEGO/GSS-API Golang packages for Kerberos authentication on MacOS

Tags: macos, kerberos

Its my follow on query to my post [How does a browser get Kerberos TGT and Service ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442497/how-does-a-browser-get-kerberos-tgt-and-service-ticket). Thanks to user1686 for a detailed explanation on that post.

For my application on Windows platform I used github.com/alexbrainman/sspi package which provides APIs to get user credentials and necessary kerberos tokens for authentication.

I now need to do the same on MacOS platform but can't use alexbrainman/sspi as it is Windows only. So far based on my research I think https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/jcmturner/gokrb5.v8 is the package suitable for use on MacOS. But only issue there is every user on MacOS will have to provide a keytab file as the gokrb5 package doesn't provide any APIs to directly get user's credentials (correct me I am wrong). Any suggestion for any other Golang packages that I can explore for Kerberos authentication on MacOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Most Unix systems offer the **GSS API** interface, which is the "standard" equivalent to Windows' SSPI. (The function names and constants are different but all of the fundamentals are the same.)

As far as I know, the Kerberos interface in macOS is `Kerberos.framework`, which is just a vendor fork of Heimdal Kerberos and still supports the same GSSAPI interface as you would find on Linux.

So you should be looking for a package that provides C GSSAPI bindings. At first glance, [openshift/gssapi](https://github.com/openshift/gssapi) should work – though it's unmaintained, but it specifically mentions macOS as compatible. Either way, GSSAPI really hasn't changed all that much since 8 years ago, so I'd still start there.

---

Pure Go implementations *may* be possible, as credentials on Unix systems are stored "in the open" – there is no real equivalent to LSASS (except for the recent gss-proxy on Linux, but I don't think macOS has an equivalent); instead the Kerberos library directly reads tickets and session keys out of the credential cache. The issue is that macOS uses a different method of accessing the cache (instead of ordinary files it uses either a Unix socket or Mach IPC), and I doubt any "pure Go" module would bother doing that.

Comment: Do you think https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gss can be used ?

Comment: Yes, if you're programming in Swift.

Comment: I think I am going to do something similar to https://github.com/dpotapov/go-spnego/blob/master/spnego_gokrb5.go.  It basically uses github.com/jcmturner/gokrb5 package, but instead of using keytab file, loads the user credentials from the ticket cache. Thanks for all your help and information you shared.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend that – it's *technically* an option, but macOS doesn't store tickets in the traditional "file" cache, so you're looking at having to support two much more complex cache types (KCM for older macOS, something Mach-based on newer). Use the system libraries.